# How does Aggressive Negotiations work?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have little need for reputation so I chose to get a high level of aggressive negotiations. Now it says I pay 90 reputation for each discount.

I assume that unlocking science parts is a single transaction.

But is making a ship with 4 of the same part 4 rounds of aggressive negotiation so 360 reputation.

Or is it calculated per part with an unlimited number, so 90 rep.

Or is it only charged on unlocking parts?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/98202-Caution-Aggressive-Negotiation-will-completely-and-Instantly-ruin-your-reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/98202-Caution-Aggressive-Negotiation-will-completely-and-Instantly-ruin-your-reputation), Aggressive Negotiations works on a per ship/launch AND on each new technology(parts not techtree node) that is unlocked.